# OpenLDAP ACLs not cooperating

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

I had a simple ACL in place on my server that was working fine. I've decided to set up SSSD to authenticate user logins via LDAP, so I need to give more access to the SSSD bind account. In the process I've somehow blocked all access beyond the first ACL; despite the `break` statement at the end of ACL {0}, every search that isn't by a root-level user returns error 32 (object not found.)

The structure of the database looks roughly like this:

```
organization: dc=r1,dc=internal
    organizationalUnit: ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
        inetOrgPerson: uid=mike,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
    organizationalUnit: ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal
        groupOfUniqueNames: cn=root,ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal
        posixGroup: cn=mike,ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal
    organizationalUnit: ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal
        inetOrgPerson: uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal
```

Here is my ACL:

```
version: 1

dn: olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
# admin users can write anything in this subtree
# also the root SASL user (eg ldapmodify -QY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// ...)
# nobody else has access, but continue searching for matches below
olcAccess: {0}to dn.subtree="dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by anonymous break
  by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=root,ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal" write
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" write
  by * break
# sssd user can read all user/group attributes
# other users keep looking
olcAccess: {1}to dn.onelevel="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
olcAccess: {2}to dn.onelevel="ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
# you can update your own password
# anonymous users can authenticate against it
# nobody else sees it
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="dc=r1,dc=internal"
  attrs=userPassword
    by self write
    by anonymous auth
    by * none
# anonymous users can read select user/group attributes
olcAccess: {4}to dn.onelevel="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  attrs=entry,cn,uid,sn,givenName,mail,telephoneNumber,mobile,memberOf
    by anonymous read
    by * break
olcAccess: {5}to dn.onelevel="ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  attrs=entry,cn,description,uniqueMember,memberUid
    by anonymous read
    by * break
# all users can update their own records
# and see all other users' attributes
# everyone (including anonymous) can search
olcAccess: {6}to dn.onelevel="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by self write
  by users read
  by * search
```

Here is a log extract with extra ACL logging:

```
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => access_allowed: search access to "ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal" "entry" requested
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => dn: [1] dc=r1,dc=internal
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => acl_get: [1] matched
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => acl_get: [1] attr entry
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => acl_mask: access to entry "ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal", attr "entry" requested
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => acl_mask: to all values by "uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal", (=0)
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: <= check a_dn_pat: anonymous
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: <= check a_dn_pat: cn=admin,dc=r1,dc=internal
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: <= check a_group_pat: cn=root,ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => mdb_entry_get: found entry: "cn=root,ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal"
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: <= check a_dn_pat: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: <= check a_dn_pat: *
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: <= acl_mask: [5] applying +0 (break)
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: <= acl_mask: [5] mask: =0
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => dn: [2] ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => dn: [3] ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => dn: [4] dc=r1,dc=internal
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => acl_get: [4] matched
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => dn: [5] ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => dn: [6] ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => dn: [7] ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: <= acl_get: done.
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => slap_access_allowed: no more rules
Aug 26 13:04:10 lemongrab slapd[3991]: => access_allowed: no more rules
```

The log entries confirm my suspicion that nothing much is being done after the first rule. Why, for example, does it jump from rule 1 to rule 4? From my understanding, rule 2 should be considered next.

I've tried both `onelevel` and `children` scopes in the ACL with the same effect. If I change the ACL to `olcAccess: {1}to dn.subtree="dc=r1,dc=internal"` it seems to work, but there are other OUs besides users and groups that I don't want to grant access to. Am I misunderstanding how the scope works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** I figured it out! The primary problem is that the documentation is subtle.  This is the description of the dnstyle qualifiers in [`slapd.access(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/slapd.access.5.html):

> The `<dnstyle>` is optional; however, it is recommended to specify
> it to avoid ambiguities.  Base (synonym of `baseObject`), the
> default, or `exact` (an alias of `base`) indicates the entry whose DN
> is equal to the `<dnpattern>`; `one` (synonym of `onelevel`) indicates
> all the entries immediately below the `<dnpattern>`, `sub` (synonym
> of `subtree`) indicates all entries in the subtree at the
> `<dnpattern>`, `children` indicates all the entries below
> (subordinate to) the `<dnpattern>`.

The key point is that `dn.one` grants access to *only* the entries
immediately below `<dnpattern>`. If you write (as you have):

```
olcAccess: {1}to dn.onelevel="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
olcAccess: {2}to dn.onelevel="ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
```

This will *fail*, because `dn.onelevel="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"`
doesn't grant the `sssd` user access to the dn
`ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal` itself. If you look at the ACL logs when
making a request, you'll see something like:

```
=> access_allowed: search access to "ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal" "entry" requested
```

You have no rules that grant this access, so it fails. We need to add
ACLs that grant access to the ou itself. That means replacing
something like this:

```
olcAccess: to dn.onelevel="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
```

With this:

```
# grant access to ou=users
olcAccess: to dn.base="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
# grant access to entries immediately below ou=users
olcAccess: to dn.onelevel="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
```

(You could replace `read` with `search` in the first ACL if you don't want `sssd` to read attributes on the ou itself.)

Here is the complete set of ACLs I've set up in my test environment:

```
dn: olcDatabase=mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: mdb
olcSuffix: dc=r1,dc=internal
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/openldap/r1.internal
# root has access to everything always
olcAccess: to *
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
  by * break
# root and members of cn=root group can access everything
olcAccess: to dn.subtree="dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by anonymous break
  by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember="cn=root,ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal" write
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" write
  by * break
# sssd user can read all users
olcAccess: to dn.base="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
olcAccess: to dn.one="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
# sssd user can read all groups
olcAccess: to dn.base="ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
olcAccess: to dn.one="ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by dn.exact="uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal" read
  by * break
# self can modify password, anon can authenticate
olcAccess: to dn.subtree="dc=r1,dc=internal"
  attrs=userPassword
    by self write
    by anonymous auth
    by * none
# anonymous can read selected user attributes
olcAccess: to dn.base="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
    by anonymous search
    by * break
olcAccess: to dn.one="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  attrs=entry,cn,uid,sn
    by anonymous read
    by * break
# anonymous can read selected group attributes
olcAccess: to dn.base="ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal"
    by anonymous search
    by * break
olcAccess: to dn.subtree="ou=groups,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  attrs=entry,cn,uniqueMember,objectClass
    by anonymous read
    by * break
# self can modify own entry, authenticated users can
# read all entries
olcAccess: to dn.base="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by * search
olcAccess: to dn.one="ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal"
  by self write
  by users read
  by * search
```

This works!  With a directory structure like this:

```
dn: ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
  dn: cn=user1,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
  dn: cn=user2,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
  dn: ou=nested,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
    dn: cn=user3,ou=nested,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
```

Then running:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -H ldap://localhost:3890 -x \
  -D uid=sssd,ou=system,dc=r1,dc=internal -w secret \
  -b ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal dn
```

Produces:

```
dn: ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal

dn: cn=user1,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal

dn: cn=user2,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal

dn: ou=nested,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
```

...which is exactly what we want: `sssd` is only able to see a single
level, and does not see users under `ou=nested`. If we perform the
same search as a member of the `root` group, we now see `user3` under
`ou=nested`:

```
dn: ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal

dn: cn=user1,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal

dn: cn=user2,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal

dn: ou=nested,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal

dn: cn=user3,ou=nested,ou=users,dc=r1,dc=internal
```

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking that's what I'm going to go with. As I said, there are other OUs that I don't want to give full access to, but I'm glad I'm not the only one stumped by it at least.

Comment: Sleeping on it made the problem more obvious :). I think this updated answer is correct.

Comment: If it's of interest, you can find my test setup [here](https://github.com/larsks/slapd-acl-test).

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. I must have read that section of the man page like 4 times. I just assumed that "below the [pattern]" was inclusive of the pattern, but a strict reading makes sense that it would mean otherwise.